# Check if by any combination of + and - of elements, an array sums to zero

Tags: python, algorithm

[The source of the question](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-set-61-internship/).

It's an interview question, so I think it should have a solution, but I'm not sure what it is and can't find any.

The problem is this:

Given an array of numbers, check if it is possible, with additions and subtractions placed anywhere, to make the sum zero.

eg:

> A={2,1,8,5}
>
> +2-1+8+5 != 0
>
> -2-1+8+5 != 0
>
> +2-1-8+5 != 0
>
> -2-1+8-5 == 0

thus done.

I already have the code for the exponential solution:

```
def isFeasible(A, p, _sum):
    if p == len(A):
        if _sum==0: return True
        else: return False;

    return (isFeasible(A, p+1, _sum+A[p]) or isFeasible(A, p+1, _sum-A[p]))


def driver(arr):
    print isFeasible(arr,0,0)
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: This is another form of the [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), a well-known np-complete problem. Plus and Minus resemble the two different groups.

Comment: It is also  the subset sum problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: @PadraicCunningham : the question is, how to distribute + and - such that the sum is zero; if there is no solution, return false. if there is a solution, returning True or the exact solution is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your numbers *A[i]* for *i = 1..N*. You need to solve the following equation:

```
  sum(X[i] * A[i]) = 0,   for X[i] = -1 or 1
```

Obviously, this is equivalent to (just change -1 to 0 in *X[]*):

```
  sum(X[i] * 2*A[i]) = sum(A[i]),   for X[i] = 0 or 1
```

The second problem is exactly the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) for numbers *(A[i])*, which is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) if numbers are arbitrary. Also, the partition problem is the simplest case of the well-known [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Just read both wikipedia articles and you'll learn a lot of ways to solve the problem.

EDIT: Yet another equivalent problem is:

```
  sum(X[i] * A[i]) = sum((1 - X[i]) * A[i])    for X[i] = 0 or 1
```

It is the same as the second equation, but now it is clearly visible that this is a partition problem: *X[i] = 1* means put element to the left, *X[i] = 0* means put element to the right. After all the elements are put, sums must be equal.

Also note that there is a pseudopolynomial solution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem), it can be also turned into a [fully polynomial approximation scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Fully_polynomial_time_approximation_scheme). Also note that the knapsack problem can be solved by [meet-in-the-middle approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Meet-in-the-middle), which reduces time complexity of exponential solution from *O(2^N)* to *O(sqrt(2)^N)*.

**Conclusion:** read the wikipedia articles on these problems, you'll find all the info there.

Comment: What is the sum(A[i]) term in the second part?

Comment: @abhidivekar It is sum of all the numbers you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your exponential solution by using [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization): if you already know the answer for `_sum`, return that. Otherwise, compute it and store it.

However, I want to present a more interesting solution. This is the official solution to a similar problem from a local online judge. In that problem, we had to find the actual assignment of `+/-` to each number, and it guaranteed that there exists a solution.

The solution was to keep two sets: a set of numbers that are added and a set of numbers that are subtracted. Then, we would randomly do the following while a solution was not found:

```
if the current sum is smaller than the target:
  move a random element from the - set to the + set
else:
  move a random element from the + set to the - set
```

While doing these moves, you can update the current sum in `O(1)`.

This worked for `50 000` numbers in under one second on the online judge. For your problem, you could see if it finds a solution under the given time constrains, and assume there isn't one if it doesn't.

I don't know if this works in general or only on specifically-crafted inputs. Maybe someone else can comment on that, but I was always surprised how well it worked on that problem and that it was the official solution.

Comment: It may be the partition problem, I'm not sure. But I think since it was asked in an interview, it could be a special case that is solvable in less than exponential time.

Comment: @abhidivekar Nope, your problem is fully equivalent (i.e. in both directions) to partition problem. There is no polynomial solution if numbers are not bounded. Note however, that there is a [pseudopolynomial solution with dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution). Just read the articles I linked, they are very detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I am missing something.

You can easily reduce this to a `Subset Sum problem` , that is given an array `a` and value `k` find out if there is a subset whose sum is `k`.

Let me explain why this problem is same as `Subset sum problem`.

Say sum of all elements in your array is `X`. What you want to do is : assign `-` sign to subset of elements whose sum `x/2` and the remaining elements assign `+` so that your total sum will be zero.

So In your question what you want to find out is if there is a subset whose sum exactly `X/2`, if there is a subarray like that then assign`-` all those elements and automatically the sum of total array will be zero.

Now your solution is:

```
     array - a
     sum of all elements -x
     return isSubsetSum(a,x/2)
```

And you can write a simple dynamic programming solution to find out this:

```
  bool isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int sum)
  {

    bool subset[sum+1][n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
      subset[0][i] = true;

    for (int i = 1; i <= sum; i++)
      subset[i][0] = false;

     // Fill the subset table in botton up manner
     for (int i = 1; i <= sum; i++)
     {
       for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
       {
         subset[i][j] = subset[i][j-1];
         if (i >= set[j-1])
           subset[i][j] = subset[i][j] || subset[i - set[j-1]][j-1];
       }
     }
     return subset[sum][n];
  }
```

Sorry, I am not good at python. Just translate this to python yourself.